# Komma vor "und"?

Tags: comma

Ich arbeite gerade an einer Projektarbeit und wollte den folgenden Satz schreiben:

> Ein neuronales Netz besteht aus mehreren Neuronen, die dazu dienen, Informationen aufzunehmen, diese zu verarbeiten(,) und an andere Neuronen weiterzuleiten.

Je länger ich über diesen Satz nachdenke, desto unsicherer werde ich... Gehört vor das "und" ein Komma oder nicht?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comma or no comma before "und"](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/33191/comma-or-no-comma-before-und)

Comment: In your case without the comma would be correct.

Comment: Englische Fragen/Antworten sind kein duplicate zu deutschen und vice versa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kurze Frage, kurze Antwort:

Hier kommt kein Komma hin, da das 'und' die Aufzählung von zwei Schritten verbindet.

Da hier drei Schritte vorkommen, ist der erste und zweite Schritt per Komma verbunden.
Bei Schrittketten werden die letzte beiden Schritte per 'und' verbunden, alle anderen davor mit Komma. Bei zwei Schritten ist halt kein Komma nötig.

Bsp:
Ich tat dies, das, solches und schloss dann ab.

Answer (score 0):

Ich bin nicht so sicher ob das *diese* nicht die Aufzählung stört. Wenn man die drei Schritte anders gruppiert, fällt das erste Komma weg, und danach kommt ein "um...zu" Teilsatz.

> Ein neuronales Netz besteht aus mehreren Neuronen, die dazu dienen,
>   Informationen aufzunehmen und zu verarbeiten, und diese dann an andere
>   Neuronen weiterzuleiten.

(ich habe nur das *diese* verschoben, und dazu ein *dann* eingefügt)

Comment: Mit meiner Kommaschwäche möchte ich nicht felsenfest behaupten, dass auch hier vor das und kein Komma kommt. Vor den anderen Neuronen würde ich aber gerne ein "an" sehen. Ebenso würde ich im geklammerten Kommentar kein Komma vor und setzen, ebenso in einleitenden Satz.