# Should there be a comma in front of "und" in the following sentence?

Tags: comma, punctuation

Consider the sentence:

> Einerseits, weil es halt einfach so ist ***,*** und andererseits, weil es auf Wikipedia steht.

Should one put the second comma?

On one hand I often hear that there shouldn't be a comma in front of "und". On the other hand, it would be plausible to break the quoted sentence into two separate sentences ("Einerseits, weil [...]. Und andererseits, weil [...]."), so why shouldn't it be possible to put the even looser separation (the comma) instead of the strong separation mark (the dot)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comma or no comma before "und"](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/33191/comma-or-no-comma-before-und)

Comment: Commas seem to be more optional in English than in German, but even the English version of the sentence should probably have three commas.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### **Yes**, the comma is obligatory here – because of the preceding subclause.

Not because of *und*, however.  It's about the subclause *weil es halt einfach so ist*. The comma rules for subclauses apply: if a sentence begins or ends with a subclause, a comma is set in between to separate them from each other. If the subclause is interposed, however, it begins **and** ends with a comma.

A comma because of *und* can only be placed if *und* connects two main clauses (but doesn't need to). However, in those cases other punctuation devices are often better suited (e.g. a semicolon, a dash or even a full stop).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the second comma is needed, because the part

> weil es halt einfach so ist

is a subordinate clause. You need to start and end a subordinate clause with commas if they appear in the middle of a sentence.

In this case, the actual main sentence is incomplete, this is probably an epiphrase to a complete sentence that stands before this one.

Nevertheless,

> Einerseits [...] und andererseits [...]

is the part of the main sentence that is still there.

Answer (score 2):

With the comma it looks like the following:

### NO COMMA

> SIMPLE LISTINGS (einfache Aufzählungen)

"Facebook, Twitter **und** Instagram."

> DISPOSED SUB-CLAUSES (unselbstständige Teilsätze)

"Ich bin schon lange auf Facebook aktiv **und** nutze Instagram erst seit Kurzem."

> SEQUELED SUBSIDIARIES (gleichgeordnete Nebensätze)

"Ich bin gerne auf Facebook, weil es wichtig für mein Marketing ist und weil ich Spaß dran habe."

### YOU CAN CHOOSE

If two separate sentences are connected by an **"und"**, you can freely decide for or against the comma. This is true even if the subject is the same:

- "Ich erstelle das Grobkonzept**[,] und** mein Kollege übernimmt später die Ausarbeitung."

The only important thing is that the second sub-sentence after the comma can stand alone as a sentence.

### COMMA MUST BE

> INSERTED ACCESSORIES (eingeschobene Nebensätze)

"Ich hoffe, dass ich Ihre Frage damit beantworten konnte**, und** wünsche Ihnen ein schönes Wochenende."

> INSERTS (Einschübe)

"Gerne helfen Tanja, meine Mitarbeiterin**, und** ich Ihnen weiter."

> ADDITIONS (Zusatz)

"Ich muss darauf unbedingt reagieren**, und** zwar schnell."

In your example, I would leave a *comma* and not a *dot* before the "und". Then with "Einerseits" and "Andererseits" you refers to something that is better dealt in one sentence. But because it is a *subordinate clause*, one could also put a point:

"Einerseits, weil es halt einfach so ist. Andererseits, weil es auf Wikipedia steht."