# I need help with personal pronouns

Tags: grammatical-case

Which one is correct and why ?                                                                    Er stellt sich **ihm** und weicht nicht zurück /                             Er stellt sich **ihn** und weicht nicht zurück /                                  zurückstellen etw.AKK / sich AKK stellen verb /

Comment: https://www.dwds.de/wb/stellen and https://www.dwds.de/wb/zur%C3%BCckweichen

Comment: It would help to provide more context here, for example what are you actually trying to say in English? I think I know what you're getting at though.

Answer (score 2):

First, I think the sentence is meant to say something like "He's confronting him and is not retreating." It's not too clear from the question; words often have multiple meanings and without context or a specific description of what you're talking about, it's difficult to give a precise answer.

There are two different clauses, and the prefix of a separable verb does not move across a conjunction to another clause. So the prefix *zurück* goes with *weichen* and has nothing to do with *stellen*. In any case, while there is a verb *zurückstellen*, I don't see any way for it to fit with the rest of the sentence. From there the [Wiktionary entry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stellen) (meaning 2) seems clear:

> (reflexive, with dative object) to expose oneself, to succumb, to come out to face, to confront

DWDS has three corresponding definitions 3a, b and c, but I think they cover the same ground only in more detail. Without context it's difficult to know which definition is meant. The DWDS label is "*sich jmdm. stellen*", which is basically the same as Wiktionary's label but without the jargon.

So you need a reflexive pronoun, in this case *sich* and a dative object, so *ihm* instead of *ihn*. I probably would have put a comma after *ihm* as well.

Comment: Why would you put a comma? I wouldn't. I would put a period at the end of the sentence, though.

Comment: @Roland: I was thinking a comma to separate the clauses, since that's more common in German than in English. I couldn't think of reason *not* to have one.

Comment: In this case there should be no comma because of the "und".

Comment: @Roland: I'm going by what I've picked up from various grammars, but it wouldn't surprise me if they don't reflect actual practice. Some examples from [Bruce Duncan's grammar site](http://www.dartmouth.edu/~deutsch/Grammatik/WordOrder/Compounds.html): *Sie wollte ihre Eltern besuchen, und ich bin mitgegangen.* *Du hast das bestellt, und jetzt musst du es essen.* I'll research this further on my own; perhaps I'll ask a question about it here if I don't find anything.

Comment: @Roland: PS. Hubert Schölnast's answer [here](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/33196/43989) seems to sum it up. Actually I had read it earlier but forgot the details. Probably the grammars I've been reading are either from before the 1996 change or don't take it into account.